# Synchronizing two pthreads using mutex in C

Tags: c, pthreads, mutex, synchronize

Need help with synchronizing two threads with mutex. Iam new to C and mutexes and Im not sure what to do here. The code has two threads that counts to ten and prints out each number, but is not synch, so it will not print synchronized, it is half synched. Means that i only get trouble in the end, sometimes it prints 8..9..11, 8..9..10..10 and so on.

I cannot make changes to the raw code, if you take away the lines about mutexes, that is the raw code. I can only add lines about mutexes.

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

pthread_mutex_t mutex;

int g_ant = 0;

void *writeloop(void *arg) {
    while(g_ant < 10) {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
        g_ant++;
        usleep(rand()%10);
        printf("%d\n", g_ant);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    }
    exit(0);
}

int main(void)
{
    pthread_t tid;
    pthread_mutex_init(&mutex, NULL);
    pthread_create(&tid, NULL, writeloop, NULL);
    writeloop(NULL);
    pthread_join(tid, NULL);
    pthread_mutex_destroy(&mutex);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: please post all of your code

Comment: `undefined reference to 'writeloop'`

Comment: Sorry, fixed the code now. Please try again :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the condition outside your mutex you may not be receiving the correct values. A guaranteed way to ensure the loop operates in-order would be the following change to `writeloop`:

```
void writeloop(void *arg) {
    while (g_ant < 10) {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
        if (g_ant >= 10) {
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
            break;
        }

        g_ant++;
        usleep(rand()%10);
        printf("%d\n", g_ant);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to mention that i cannot make changes to the raw code. If you take away the codelines about mutexes, that is the raw code. Im trying to synchronize the threads by adding mutexes. Is there another solution for this?

Comment: If you added code for the mutexes, you can surely change the code in other ways. You could place the `while (g_ant < 10)` condition back again if you wanted it to be "minimal"...

Comment: Thank you so much. I thought it was my placement of the mutex_unlock or lock that was wrong so i unlocked or locked or destroyed the mutex before the threads were done counting. So it was nothing like that?

Comment: Nope, consider the case where Thread A reads `g_ant` as 9 locks the mutex and at this point thread B reads `g_ant` as 9 and blocks on the mutex. A will make `g_ant` 10 then print and unlock; B will *also* make `g_ant` 10 then print and unlock. Because there is no protection on the condition you have no guarantee it will not be invalidated by another thread before/during/after you read it.

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply! It was really helpful :)